# How to properly implement/overload "__repr__ "?

Tags: python, overloading

New to python and this might be a silly question, but how does one properly implement the *repr* method?

I wrote a quick little program to simulate a game of cards but I don't know what to write for the *repr* method. The *repr* method for the **Card class** was pretty straight forward, but I don't know what to do for the **DeckOfCards class** Here's my code:

```
import random
class Card:
'''Create a single card, by id number'''

# Class variables, created once for the class
    suits = [ '\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663' ]
    ranks = [ 'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K' ]

    def __init__(self, n=0):
    # instance variables for _num, _rank, _suit, _value
    if 0 <= n < 52:
        self._num = n
        self._rank = Card.ranks[n%13]       # note referencing class vars
        self._suit = Card.suits[n//13]
        self._value = n%13 + 1
        if self._rank == 'A':
            self._value = 14
    else: # invalid card indicators
        self._rank = 'x'
        self._suit = 'x'
        self._value = -1

    def __repr__(self):
        return  self._rank + self._suit

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self._value < other._value

    def __le__(self,other):
        return self._value <= other._value

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self._value == other._value

class DeckOfCards:
'''A Deck is a collection of cards'''

    def __init__(self):
        self._deck = [ Card(i) for i in range(52) ]

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Deck : ', self._deck

    def shuffle(self):
        return random.shuffle(self._deck)

    def deal_a_card(self, i=-1):
    #that way player can choose where to draw from 
        return self._deck.pop(i)

    def cards_left(self,count):
        return len(self._deck)

new_deck = DeckOfCards()
```

Also, feel free to comment on anything you'd like, whether it be a design flaw or redundancy in code, literally anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a string type, for example in Deck:

```
def __repr__(self):
    ...
    return 'Deck : '+str(self._deck)
```

Comment: That's how I had it before hand but it just seemed wasteful converting it to a string every time. But, yes that would do.

Comment: Mark the question answered so that people don't continue to post answers. :)

Comment: Time limitation, it was answered too fast. But will do, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`__repr__` ideally could return the representation of the object that you would use to create this instance.

From [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr):

> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(), otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object.

Answer (score 0):

First, It should be noted that you don't *have* to implement the `__repr__` method.  Python provides a somewhat reasonable default (it'll at least tell you the type).

If you want to implement `__repr__`, the "rule of thumb" is that where it makes sense, you should provide enough information about the object that a user could reconstruct it.  In your case, there doesn't seem to be any real difference from one deck to another, so

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Deck()'
```

*might* be a reasonable return value.  This doesn't get the state right (after shuffling), but you don't provide an interface for constructing a deck in a particular state.  If you did, it might look like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Deck(%s)' % self._deck
```

Comment: I am aware of the default method but I needed it formatted in a specific way.